# Method for precise calculation?

Tags: tactics, calculation

I'm tired of being stuck on a chesstempo rating 1530-1570 tactics in Blitz for like 5 days I'm "not" improving. Sometimes I  take more than 2 minutes and sometimes I just move on quickly to the next puzzle to satisfy my ego. Is there a perfect way to calculate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being stuck for 5 days is not a long period of time. Players get stuck at their levels for months or even years. It could just be that you got a particularly hard sequence of puzzles, or that you didn't sleep well, or many different reasons.

There is no "perfect" way to calculate. If there was, chess would be a very uninteresting game. You could just give 20 bucks to someone to explain you what that method is and congratulations! You've made it to GM!

As general advice, you should calculate forced moves first (checks, then captures, then immediate threats...) You can apply this recursively (start by your forced moves, search for the forced replies from your opponent, then your forced replies to his reply and so on... The reason why you should give preference to these moves is that, on one hand they are simpler to analyze and on the other, when they do work, they are often game-changers

Answer (score 3):

Being stuck at a certain level is not unusual and I would not worry about it.

Since you asked specifically about "precise calculation"...

You should be aware that solving tactics is not only about being able to calculate accruately many moves deep. It is also about recognizing certain patterns / tactical motifs that appear in every puzzle.

Particularly at your level it is much more likely that you fail some puzzles because you are not aware of a motif, rather than missing a defensive option many moves down the line that you did not calculate.

After you solved a puzzle or failed to do so, chesstempo shows you the motifs. Make sure you understand each of these motifs in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

When I focused on tactics every day my rating when up about 100 points after 6 months.  Then it went up 400 points in a week and leveled off again.  This is where I am 6 months later, but I am hopeful. Keep at it, you will get there.

Comment: Wow!400 in a week!.How much points did it leveled down?And what was your rating and also how many puzzles were you doing per day?

Comment: I was doing 60 puzzles / day.  My rating was 1500 -> 1600 -> 2000